# How to load page to particular element with load()

Tags: html, jquery

I have content that will be reload with load() on each time checkbox is selected/unselected.

The problem is when content is to hight and you need to scroll down after every load page is going on top and you need to scroll down again is there anyway to display page at same position ?

For example if you use click on group Height then to load page on href #126

i was thinking to use scrollTop element after page reload but is look terrible for user experience

```
     <div class="filters">
      <div class="filter-wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <a href="#5">Width</a>
          <div class="options">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="10 m">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="20 m">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="30 m">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <a href="#126">Height</a>
          <div class="options">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="100 kg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="200 kg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="300 kg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <a href="#38">Color</a>
          <div class="options">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Green">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Red">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="Blue">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.option input').click(function(){
        $('.filter-wrapper').load('index.php?route=product/filter&path=<?php echo $path ?>'+selected_filters);
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen.

Comment: @Barmar to show page at position where you click on checkbox because now after load() page is scrolled to the top and you have to scroll down again

Comment: The title and the question are asking two completely different things.

Comment: Perhaps you could add additional HTML/css/js to your snippet to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Does this question help? [scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/scroll-to-an-element-with-jquery) - add it in the `.load` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that the page automatically reloads whenever a checkbox is clicked. So keeping that thing in mind the code mentioned below will work.

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
    //fetch the location of the div that is clicked
    $('.options').click(function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;

        //save the x,y coordinates in a cookie
        $.cookie('xCord', x);
        $.cookie('yCord', y);
    });

   //fetch the cookie saved after click event and store it in a var
   var xCord = $.cookie("xCord");
   var yCord= $.cookie("yCord");

   //check if the saved cookie is set and is not empty
   if(typeof(xCord) != "undefined" && xCord !== null && typeof(yCord) != "undefined" && yCord!== null) {
       scrollWin(xCord,yCord);
   }

   function scrollWin(x,y) {
       window.scrollTo(x,y);
   }
});
```

Comment: @bobi If the solution worked an upvote on this answer will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

After loading the page, you can use `element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY` to retrieve the relative position of the element on the document (in this case the clicked checkbox). Use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to scroll to that position, so that the user does not have to scroll down to the checkbox.